# Which edition of the Restlet framework is the correct one for GWT and GAE projects?

Tags: java, android, google-app-engine, gwt, restlet

I'm new to RESTlet and reading [their documentation](http://wiki.restlet.org/docs_2.1/13-restlet/21-restlet/318-restlet/303-restlet.html) on setting up a sample service.  It says that the "Restlet Framework 2.1 Milestone 4" is necessary, but on the [download page](http://www.restlet.org/downloads/testing) for that version there are many choices, none of which are specifically called out as "the framework."

So to build the GWT and GAE demo, should I be installing the Edition for Java EE, the Edition for Google AppEngine or the Edition for Google Web Toolkit?  They all provide different jar files, or in the case of common jar files, their contents differ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is you need each of them for different things.  The first project I wanted to build was org.restlet.example.serialization.gae-gwt, and it required both the Restlet GWT ( restlet-gwt-2.1rc5 ) and the Restlet GAE ( restlet-gae-2.1rc5 ).